# Indication required for up voted comment in Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, voting, android-app

**There is no indication for the comments on question which I have already up-voted.**

In app, user can do vote-up as many as he wants to play with it (Though its not incrementing up vote counter on Web or app) but there should be 2 things:

1. It should be disable or shouldn't show vote-up option if user has already voted up comment.
2. At the same, it should show indication (same as on site) that the particular comments are up-voted by me.

Comment: Maybe bolding the number of upvotes next to the comment could be an indicator?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett yes it should be same as site (Black colored up vote icon).

Answer (score 1):

This was implemented in a UI refresh a while back for comments. This is what it looks like now:

[image]